# Read file content and store as an array

Tags: php, html, listview

I want to read log from a file and display it as a list in my Admin panel. I was pretty much sure that this code should work, but apparently it doesn't. The loop doesn't print anything in the list, and the two lines above the loop print just the first line in the file. I guess the problem is in my construction of the array `log`. Since this project is my first time use of PHP (usually I work with C), don't judge.

```
<select name=servers size=50 style=width:1028px>
<?php
  $start="0";
  $start=$_POST['start'];

  if ($start=="1") {
   //start the server, this works.
  }
  elseif ($start=="2") {
    $log=fopen("file.log", "r");
    $asdf = sprintf ("<option >%s</option>", $log);
    echo $asdf; //these two lines are for testing purposes,
       //they print only one line of the file in the list. 

    $i=0;
    while ($log[$i]!=null) {
      $asdf[$i] = sprintf ("<option >%s</option>", $log[$i]);
      echo $asdf[$i];
      $i++; //this loop is the problem, doesn't print anything.
    }
    echo fread($log,filesize("file.log"));
    echo $log;
  }
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have initialized `$asdf` as a `string` and then use it like an `array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
$log=fopen("file.log", "r");
```

use

```
$log=file("file.log");
```

Also change the while loop to

```
foreach($log as $logline) {
    // print $logline the way you want
}
```

The reason why your code isn't working is that [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) returns a handle of the file and you need special functions to use it: `fread, fclose, feof` etc. The `file()` function reads the whole file into an array (each element is a line) so for small and medium-sized text files it's an ideal way to go.

Comment: Yep, $log=file("file.log"); this one helped. Thanks, it works now!

Comment: And just to mention that foreach doesn't work for me. I tried it also on another list I was making, didn't work, and now doesn't work either. I'll stay with my while loop.

Answer (score 0):

[fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) returns a file handler, not an array.  To read line by line, you can use [fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) in your while loop:

```
while (($line = fgets($log)) !== false) {
    $asdf[$i] = sprintf ("<option >%s</option>", $line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the while, maybe use a foreach ?

```
while ($log[$i]!=null) {
              $asdf[$i] = sprintf ("<option >%s</option>", $log[$i]);
              echo $asdf[$i];
              $i++; //this loop is the problem, doesn't print anything.
            }
```

=>

```
foreach ($logs as $log) {
              $asdf[$i] = sprintf ("<option >%s</option>", $log);
              echo $asdf[$i];
              $i++; //this loop is the problem, doesn't print anything.
            }
```

Something like this ?